# Сравнение двух чисел

Tags: ассемблер

Требуется сравнить два числа и узнать, какое из них больше.

Сделать это нужно на теоретическом ассемблере, у которого отсутствуют команды сравнения и вычитания.

Вот, что есть: `add` (сложение), `not` (вычисление обратного кода) и `jmn` (условный прыжок. выполняется, когда значение регистра < 0). Соответственно из этого нужно придумать какое-то сравнение...

Пробовал так:

```
add a
not
add b
not
jmn someLabel  ; a - b < 0  ==>> a < b, прыгаем
```

Но, кажется, не работает. Как с заданными командами реализовать вычитание?

---

Обновление: наверное, можно переформулировать вопрос следующим образом: как с помощью сложения и преобразования в обратный код выполнить вычитание?

Answer (score 2):

Вспомните представление отрицательных чисел в дополнительном коде.

```
-a == not a + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Формула в ответе @reshu правильная, но для имплементации этого вам нужны, скорее всего, и другие команды. Например, загрузка константы. (Или ваши команды должны работать и с константами тоже.) Кроме того, должны быть команды загрузки/копирования (и скорее всего оперативные регистры), если мы не хотим испортить значения переменных.

```
# a < b <=> a - b < 0 <=> a + (-b) < 0 <=> a + ~b + 1 < 0
load b   # into register
not      # register = ~b
add a    # register = a + ~b
add 1    # register = a + ~b + 1
jmn aIsLess
```